# How can I represent data with optional fields at the type-level?

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a data for control flow that has a value (polymorphic, can be whatever), and it also *could* have a validator function that checks if the value is still good, and *could* have a function that "refreshes the value" (returns a new data with a new value).

In vanilla Haskell it can look like this:

```
data MyData a = MyData
  {value :: a
  ,validator :: Maybe (a -> Bool)
  ,refresher :: Maybe (MyData a -> MyData a)}
```

What I actually want are these types:

```
data Refreshable = Refreshable | NotRefreshable
data Validatable = Validatable | NotValidatable
MyData (r :: Refreshable) (v :: Validatable)
```

I've done just that but only with `Refreshable`. I want to do it with `Validatable` too but I'm having a problem with constructors. Just for `Refreshable` I need to have two constructors, one for refreshable data and another for non-refreshable data. With validatable, I'll need to have 4 constructors! (for refreshable and validatable, for non-refreshable and validatable, for validatable and non-refreshable, and for non-refreshable and non-validatable). And imagine if I'll need another optional field later. Even worse: almost all the fields are the same except for the ones that are changing so there's so much duplication.

---

I've also tried to amend the situation with typeclasses / type-families.
For example, `MyData 'Refreshable 'NotValidatable` just becomes `Refreshable data => data` and I could instance `MyData` or just remove it for more specific-data that can be an instance.

This is also problematic, because they're not really fields anymore; i.e. I can't take a data without a validator and change it to the same data *with* a validator (not at the type-level).

---

This is probably an XY problem; I think a cleaner approach would be to make data types like `Refreshable a` and `Validatable a` and compose them in `MyData` but I don't know how to do that. I can't wrap them because order would change everything.

Is there a clean way to do this? or should I just stick with the 4 constructors? or maybe Haskell isn't ready for this type of things yet? (no pun intended :P).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would something like this satisfy your requirements?

```
import Control.Applicative (Const)
import Data.Functor.Identity

data MyData kv kr a = MyData
  {value :: a
  ,validator :: kv (a -> Bool)
  ,refresher :: kr (MyData a -> MyData a)}

-- examples
type FullData a      = Data Identity   Identity   a
type EmptyData a     = Data (Const ()) (Const ()) a
type ValidableData a = Data Identity   (Const ()) a
```

Some wrapping/unwrapping required (for `Identity`).

It is possible to define mnemonic aliases `type Present = Identity` and `type Missing = Const ()`, with a few extensions on.

---

Alternatively,

```
data MyData (v :: Opt) (r :: Opt) a = MyData
  {value :: a
  ,validator :: Validator v a
  ,refresher :: Refresher r a}

data Opt = Yes | No

type family Validator (o :: Opt) a where
    Validator Yes = (a -> Bool)
    Validator No  = ()
-- etc.

-- examples
type FullData a      = Data Yes Yes a
type EmptyData a     = Data No  No  a
type ValidableData a = Data Yes No  a
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with a variation from chi's answer:

```
data Opt = Yes | No

type family TOpt (o :: Opt) a where
  TOpt Yes a = a
  TOpt No a = ()
```

And then something like this:

```
data MyData (v :: Opt) a = MyData
  {val :: a
  ,validator :: TOpt v (MyData 'Yes a -> Bool)
  ...
  }
```