# Apply type constructor to components of a record type

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Given a fixed type constructor T, and a record type R, is there a mechanism to create a declaration for the record type whose components are those of R, but with T applied to the type.

For example, with T being `Maybe`, and R,

```
data Foo {
  bar :: Int,
  baz :: Bool
}
```

the mechanism should give,

```
data Foo {
  bar :: Maybe Int,
  baz :: Maybe Bool
}
```

Or possibly,

```
data FooOpt {
  barOpt :: Maybe Int,
  bazOpt :: Maybe Bool
}
```

where the `Opt` suffix is specified as a parameter.

Comment: Could you solve this with something as simple as `data Foo f { bar :: f Int, baz :: f Bool }`, then `type FooOpt = Foo Maybe`? Or do you need the type safety of separate types?

Comment: No, I cannot touch the original type.

Comment: Are you sure you can't generalize the original type, so to use a nearly isomorphic one instead as Alexis suggests? Otherwise, I guess Template Haskell is your only option, but I wonder why you really need this.

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229211/how-can-i-represent-data-with-optional-fields-at-the-type-level) close enough to your goal?

Comment: Do you actually need a proper `data` declaration (in that case there's no way around TH), or do you only need _some type that's isomorphic_ to the modified `R`? In that case a solution with generics alone might be possible (which of course requires a `Generic` instance for `R`, but that shouldn't be a hurdle).

Comment: generics-sop can do something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020787/is-there-a-way-to-apply-maybe-constructor-to-each-field-of-record-with-generics

Answer (score 2):

You can parametrize your type with another type (usually a functor) and do

```
data Foo f {
   bar :: f Int
   baz :: f Bool
}
```

And they use `Foo Identity` and `Foo Maybe`. The problem with this is `Foo Identity` doesn't give you `{bar :: Int, baz :: Bool}` but `{bar :: Identity Int, baz :: Identity Bool}`. It's semantically equivalent but a pain in practice because you have to unwrap all field from Identity.

The advantages however, is you can write method which are generic on `f` and work for both `Foo Identity` and `Foo Maybe`. You can get rid of the `Identity` by using type families.

```
type family EraseIdentity f a where
     EraseIdentity Identity a = a
     EraseIdentity f a = f a

 data Foo f = Foo {
      bar :: EraseIdentity f Int
      baz :: EraseIdentity f Bool
 }
```

Type families are function on types, and what you are saying here is , transforms `Identity a` to `a`. Now `Foo Identity` is a `{ bar :: Int, baz :: Bool}`.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about EraseIdentity